# Includes in MultiDimensional Array

Tags: javascript

```
econst ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
{position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
{position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
{position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
{position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'}
];
```

How return boolean if the value is inside of this array?
some thing like this

```
ELEMENT_DATA.includes({name: 'Helium'});
>True
```

Comment: some thing like this

ELEMENT_DATA.includes({name: 'Helium'});
>True

Comment: I see a single-dimensional array in your code. An array of objects specifically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method which will tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test

```js
const ELEMENT_DATA = [{
    position: 1,
    name: 'Hydrogen',
    weight: 1.0079,
    symbol: 'H'
  },
  {
    position: 2,
    name: 'Helium',
    weight: 4.0026,
    symbol: 'He'
  },
  {
    position: 3,
    name: 'Lithium',
    weight: 6.941,
    symbol: 'Li'
  },
  {
    position: 4,
    name: 'Beryllium',
    weight: 9.0122,
    symbol: 'Be'
  }
];
let m = ELEMENT_DATA.some(function(item) {
  return item.name === 'Helium'
});
console.log(m)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could handover array, key and value for checking the objects.

```js
function check(array, key, value) {
    return array.some(object => object[key] === value);
}

var periodicElements = [{ position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H' }, { position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He' }, { position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li' }, { position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be' }];

console.log(check(periodicElements, 'name', 'Helium'));
```